# Javafx/FXML: conflict between initialize() method and FXML Loader:Initialize: NullPointerException, FXML.LoadException

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, initialization, fxml

as the Title states, there is a certain conflict between initialize method which builds the Table and adds all content to the Table and the FXMLLoader, which is supposed to load an FXML for a Pop-Up Window.

My Code:

Main:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    private TableView<Artikel> table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(1250);
    stage.setHeight(1000);

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml1.fxml"));

    Scene scene1 = new Scene(root,300,300);


    stage.setScene(scene1);
    stage.show();

}
```

FXML 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.event.ActionEvent?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Pos?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections ?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="Controller" stylesheets="stylesheet.css" spacing="4" fx:id="idScene" >

<TableView fx:id="idTable" >

</TableView>

 <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT">
        <Button fx:id="idNew" text ="Neu" onAction="#onNew"/>

</HBox>



</VBox>
```

Controller.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Controller implements Initializable  {

    @FXML
    private Button idNew;
    @FXML
    private TableView idTable;


    public void onNew(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent popUpFenster = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml2.fxml"));
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(popUpFenster,500,500);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene2);

        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        stage.showAndWait();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        TableColumn place = new TableColumn("Platz");
        TableColumn name = new TableColumn("Name");
        TableColumn weight = new TableColumn("Gewicht");
        TableColumn price = new TableColumn("Preis");
        TableColumn amount = new TableColumn("Anzahl");




        idTable.getColumns().addAll(place,name,weight,price,amount);

        final ObservableList<Artikel> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Artikel(1,"Hallo Welt",4,5,3),
                new Artikel(1,"Hallo Welt",5,3,4),
                new Artikel(2,"Hallo Welt",4,3,1));                


        //Step : 3#  Associate data with columns  
            place.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Artikel,Integer>("Platz"));

            name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Artikel,String>("Name"));

            weight.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Artikel,Integer>("Gewicht"));

            price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Artikel,Integer>("Preis"));

            amount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Artikel,Integer>("Anzahl"));





        //Step 4: add data inside table
            idTable.setItems(data);


    }
    public class Artikel {

        private int Platz;
        private String Name;
        private int Gewicht;
        private int Preis;
        private int Anzahl;


        public Artikel() {
            this.Platz = 0;
            this.Name = "Hallo Welt";
            this.Gewicht= 0;
            this.Preis = 0;
            this.Anzahl = 0;
        }

        public Artikel(int Platz, String Name, int Gewicht, int Preis,int Anzahl) {
            this.Platz = Platz;
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Gewicht = Gewicht;
            this.Preis = Preis;
            this.Anzahl = Anzahl;
        }


        public int getPlatz() {return this.Platz;};
        public String getName () {return this.Name;}
        public int getGewicht() {return this.Gewicht;};
        public int getPreis() {return this.Preis;}
        public int getAnzahl() { return this.Anzahl;}
    }

}
```

fxml2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.event.ActionEvent?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Pos?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections ?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="290.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="Controller" stylesheets="stylesheet.css" fx:id="idPopUp">

<HBox alignment="CENTER">
    <Label text="Platz"/>
    <TextField fx:id="idPlace" />
</HBox>


</VBox>
```

**The Issue:** If you delete initialize or it comment it out -  Neu-**Button**-PopUp - work, if not - the table is shown but the button pop up doesn't, there seem to be a conflict

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: plus: a [mcve] needs the complete stacktrace of the error. Without, just guessing: there is no conflict (which you would resolve by re-naming the member that's not required by an interface) - but a mis-nomer in your fxml (or code, depending on perspective :)

Comment: ahh .. there's a strict one:one relationship between an fxml and a controller class - you _must not_ reuse the same controller in differenct views (because each will inject only the part that it knows about, leaving the fields injected by the other at null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `fxml2.fxml` you have : `fx:controller="Controller"`

The assigned controller calls `fxml2.fxml` by : 
`Parent popUpFenster = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml2.fxml"));`

So `fxml2` invokes `Controller` and then `Controller` invokes `fxml2` .......

Comment: Thank you! i changed fxml2 to a another controller and - it worked! Thank you!!!